# Redirection issue using push state / pop state - with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-history

I have the following scenario on my website.. When a user is on the payment(checkout) page and hits the back button, an error page is displayed by default.

I would like my user to be redirected on the homepage!

I have tried the following code:

```
function extractDomain(url) {
    var domain;
    if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) {
      domain = url.split('/')[2];
    }
    else {
            domain = url.split('/')[0];
    }
    domain = domain.split(':')[0];

    return domain;
}

var url = extractDomain(window.location.href);

if(jQuery("#checkout_page".length=1)){
    history.pushState(null, null, url);

    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
       window.location.assign("http://"+url)
   });
}
```

There is the following problem with the above code:

When the user is on the checkout page, the domain is appended to the user (due to the push state).

Is there any way, i can keep the exact behavior/redirection BUT WITHOUT having to append the domain at the end of the url?

Also, is this the legitimate way i am doing to achieve the redirection / is there any better way to do this?

Any help would much be appreciated

Regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working :)

I simply had to push the current url..

```
line => history.pushState(null, null, url);
change to => history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
```